# Fix nav bar to adjust when user zooms in

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am having trouble making my nav bar adjust when the user has a zoomed in browser.

For example, at zoom 100%, the nav bar looks as it should, however, if the user were to have their screen set at zoom 150%, half of my nav bar gets cut off.

Here is my HTML/CSS:

https://jsfiddle.net/ghy09hvL/3/

HTML:

```
<header>
    <div id="menu_icon"></div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <div class="transition">
                <div class="sideBar">
                    <li><a href="about.html" class="selected">About</a>

                    </li>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="transition">
                <div class="sideBar">
                    <li><a href="resume.html" class="selected">Resume</a>

                    </li>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="transition">
                <div class="sideBar">
                    <li><a href="skills.html" class="selected">Skills</a>

                    </li>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="transition">
                <div class="sideBar">
                    <li><a href="portfolio.html" class="selected">Portfolio</a>

                    </li>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="transition">
                <div class="sideBar">
                    <li><a href="gallery.html" class="selected">Map&nbsp;Gallery</a>

                    </li>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="transition">
                <div class="sideBar">
                    <li><a href="thesis.html" class="selected">Thesis</a>

                    </li>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="transition">
                <div class="sideBar">
                    <li><a href="contact.html" class="selected">Contact</a>

                    </li>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!--end sidebar-->
</header>
```

CSS:

```
@media (min-width:1100px){
     header {
         display: block;
         position: fixed;
         top: 0;
         left: 0;
         width: 260px;
         min-height: 100%;
         padding: 0 0 0 50px;
         background: #FFFFFF;
         float: left;
         overflow: hidden;
         z-index: 9999;
     }
     header nav ul {
         display: block;
         overflow: hidden;
         margin-top: 30px;
         margin-left: -15px;
         list-style: none;
     }
     header nav ul li {
         display: block;
         margin-bottom: 30px;
         margin-top: 50px;
     }
     header nav ul li a {
         color: #000000;
         font-family:"raleway-regular", arial;
         font-size: 20px;
         text-decoration: none;
         letter-spacing: 2px;
     }
     header nav ul li a:hover {
         color: #8AE6B8;
     }
     header nav ul li a:active {
         color: #CC99FF;
     }
     .transition {
         width:50%;
         height: 30px;
         position: relative;
         transition: 0.5s;
     }
     .transition:hover {
         width:100%;
         height: 30px;
         position: relative;
         transition: 0.5s;
     }
     .sideBar {
         width:75%;
         height: 100%;
         position: relative;
         padding:0px;
         margin-left:20%;
     }
     header .footer {
         position: absolute;
         bottom: 50px;
     }
}
```

Thanks so much in advance! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Use the @media rule to fix this.
It can also make your page mobile friendly.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

EDIT: I would change your fixed positioning to absolute to avoid this. But if you're dead set on the fixed position, you could update your media query to allow overflow-y: scroll. That way instead of getting cut off the user can scroll the nav if they are zoomed in too far.

You should also remove all your divs, unless you have a good reason for them other than to transition. Here's what I did:

```
header {
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 260px;
     padding: 0 0 0 50px;
     background: #FFFFFF;
     float: left;
     overflow: hidden;
     z-index: 9999;
 }
header nav {
     width:75%;
     height: 100%;
     position: relative;
     padding:0px;
     margin-left:20%;
 }
 header nav ul {
     display: block;
     overflow: hidden;
     margin-top: 30px;
     margin-left: -15px;
     list-style: none;
 }
 header nav ul li {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 30px;
     margin-top: 50px;
     width:50%;
     height: 30px;
     position: relative;
 }
 header nav ul li a {
     color: #000000;
     font-family:"raleway-regular", arial;
     font-size: 20px;
     text-decoration: none;
     letter-spacing: 2px;
     transition: 0.5s;
 }
 header nav ul li a:hover {
     color: #8AE6B8;
     padding-left: 20%;
 }
 header nav ul li a:active {
     color: #CC99FF;
 }

 header .footer {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 50px;
 }
```

html:

```
<header>
    <div id="menu_icon"></div>
    <nav>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="about.html" class="selected">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="resume.html" class="selected">Resume</a></li>
            <li><a href="skills.html" class="selected">Skills</a></li>
            <li><a href="portfolio.html" class="selected">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html" class="selected">Map&nbsp;Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="thesis.html" class="selected">Thesis</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html" class="selected">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!--end sidebar-->
 </header>
```

Comment: Sorry, I have have "@media (min-width:1100px){" at the top of the header. Will update the code. Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the viewport tag in your head, try using vw and vh for your fonts.

viewport tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" >
```

CSS something like this

```
     header nav ul li a {
        color: #000000;
        font-family:"raleway-regular", arial;
        font-size: 5vh;
        font-size: 5vh;
        text-decoration: none;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
     }
```

Comment: Just tried this, it made the fotn size bigger, but it still did not do anything to change when the page is zoomed in.

Comment: it may be because you are using pixels for your sizes on width.  When i write code viewport using vp tag, i like to use %'s and vw/vh.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I just had to change around the `position: relative` and `position: absolute` to be consistent.

All is good, thanks everyone.